# GRML will not boot automatically

Tags: linux, boot, live-usb, grml

I install [GRML](http://grml.org/) on my USB disk with the `grml2usb` tool. But when I boot from the USB, it first boots to a blank screen with `boot:` text on it. I must type the boot options myself to boot the system. I want it to boot to the system automatically. 
How can I do it? I am new to GRML, and I checked their wiki, but did not find the solution.

Comment: What are the things you have to type to boot the system?

Comment: It would be faster to ask the GRML people directly. They are pretty helpful. I'd first give the irc channel on freenode a shot, #grml. Alternatively you could try the mailing lists or issue tracker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found the problem is caused by `syslinux`.
You must have the right version to work with `grml2usb`. The best bet is to execute the `grml2usb` from the live system boot from the ISO. It must work, or blame the grml team :)